# Not able to get data in content page through javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I have created a small web application for display the selected employees data. In this application I coded a javascript. I have create a dropdownbox with username details along with them a checkbox is in front of every user. These username get from database.
 I want that manager dropdown the list and select the employee which he want to see the details. I did this with the help of javascript but the issue is that it successfully display the usernames in dropdown when it is saparate form from the master page but when i merge it with master page means make it content page of that master page it doesn't display the usernames in dropdown.

 It display it blank. Where I m doing wrong. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As Pleun says the masterpage will change the HTML control ids rendered to the browser.  There are a couple of ways round this If you are using asp.net 4 you can specify the client ids as follows:

```
<asp:Label Text="text" runat="server" ID="SomeID" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

That will maintain the ID rendered to the browser.

If you are user a previous version of asp.net then i tend to user JQuery to get the controls using something like:

```
$("[id$='SomeId']")
```

The `$=` means ends with.

You can also user server markup mixed in with your javascript code e.g.

```
var control = document.getElementById("<% =SomeId.ClientId %>");
```

asp.net will then render out whatever client side id it assigns to the control with server id SomeId

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it but no solution. Actually I need to run javascript code to Masterpage or content page. But it runs successfully in saparate default page. I think my content page code could not be able to get the controls ID in content page which is defined in javascript through document.getElementById('ddlLoginName'). If you have any other solution for this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The master page changes the names of the controls:

Have a look here:
http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs

(Not your question - but the functionality can also be done out of the box with ASP.NET without coding javascript yourself)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the client id of the controls in the function.
When you were using master page den the id of ur controls changes.
For eg:
The clientID of Checkbox chktest will be chktest without master page.But with masterpage the clientID changes to something like 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chktest'

So the javascript will not detect if you use chktest when using master page and your functions wont work as expected.So use clientId of controls.